# Downloading QGIS for MacOS

Tags: qgis, installation, mac

I have MacOS Catalina 10.15.7. I try to download QGIS version 3.16. My computer says "this type of file can harm computer" do i "keep" or "discard".

How do I acquire QGIS for my computer without subjecting it to harm/damage?

Answer (score 1):

It just means that devs are yet to complete all of Apples requirements for an installer for Mac.
QGIS is a trusted app so say ”keep” and do as instructed for the first launch under the ’download for MacOS’ section
https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html